# Hidden Revelations? Carry On!

Tags: knowledge

Each of the ellipses represents an as-yet-unknown category. The three overlapping ellipses form seven regions and one tile belongs to each region. Two have been placed for you - your task is to place the other five - so which go where and why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I finally have a full solution for this one (with a final helpful push from @Retudin in comments to fix one of my category descriptions):

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

With the ellipses explained as follows:

> *Top left:* Famous fictional wearers of **black capes**
>
>  DRACULA, [VADER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Vader), [ZORRO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorro), VAN BRUNT (the Headless Horseman from the various incarnations of [*Sleepy Hollow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Sleepy_Hollow)).
>
>  *Top right:* Famous fictional wearers of **masks**
>
>  VADER, [LECTER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_Lecter), [REID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Ranger), ZORRO.
>
>  *Bottom:* Famous fictional **horse-riders**
>
>  [GODIVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Godiva), VAN BRUNT, ZORRO, REID.

These categories would then fully satisfy the title:

> *Hidden* = wearing capes and/or masks;
>  *Revelations... carry on* = an allusion to "Four [Horsemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Horsemen_of_the_Apocalypse) of the Apocalypse", people carried upon horseback.

Comment: However, this all being said, 'Big D' does have a couple of [potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_(Universal_film_series)) [franchises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula_(Hammer_film_series)) too, so I believe there might be something even more specific about this category that I've not quite spotted yet...

Comment: @stiv- if you want a suggestion : rot13 V jbhyq fhttrfg znfxf nf pngrtbel

Comment: @Retudin (facepalm) Of course! Excellent spot - and I don't need to rearrange the graph :)